# What is causing this white box inside my Jquery Accordion?

Tags: jquery, accordion

So, I've got a pretty basic Jquery Accordion all done up, but for the life of me I cannot pick out what is causing this white box inside my accordion content.

I will post my JSFiddle link here for ease of access to my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/bQ5Gd/1/

I'm sure one of you will pick it off in seconds, I'm just very beginner at JQUERY.

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">

<h3>This is a test<h3>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed libero metus, aliquet vel euismod id, mattis sed quam. Nulla interdum leo adipiscing enim commodo hendrerit vel vitae lectus. Vivamus vehicula orci ac leo luctus ac egestas purus eleifend. Vivamus ac mauris risus, quis tempor massa. .</p>
    </div>
</div> <b>This text moves down with ACCORDION</b>
```

**Javascript**

```
  $(function () {
      $("#accordion").accordion({
          event: "click",
          active: false,
          collapsible: true,
          autoHeight: false

      });
  });
```

**CSS**

```
#accordion {

    width: 400px;

}

#accordion .ui-accordion-content > * {

    margin: 0px;

}

#accordion .ui-accordion-content {

    width: 100%;

    background-color: #777;

    color: #000;

    border: none;

    font-size: 10pt;

    line-height: 15pt;

}

#accordion .ui-accordion-content a {

    color: #777;

}

#accordion .ui-accordion-header {

    background-color: #ccc;

    margin-left: auto;

    margin-right: auto;

    border: #fff;

}

#accordion .ui-accordion-header {

    background-color: #fff;

    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #fff 100%);

    /* FF3.6+ */

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottombottom, color-stop(0%, #fff), color-stop(100%, #fff));

    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #fff 100%);

    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #fff 100%);

    /* Opera 11.10+ */

    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #fff 100%);

    /* IE10+ */

    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottombottom, #fff 0%, #fff 100%);

    /* W3C */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fa9300', endColorstr='#dc621e', GradientType=0);

    /* IE6-9 */
```

}

Comment: copy your code from jsfiddle and paste it in your question, a link to it isn't enough. That's the purpose behind the code requirement. Since you question doesn't have code, it is completely useless when jsfiddle goes down, or in networks that don't have access to it for whatever reason.

Comment: The image has a white background. It's not a transparent PNG.

Comment: Fixed the code, and I meant for the content section ahren, Thanks

Comment: upvoted. thanks for asking this question

Answer (score 2):

Use an inspection tool in your browser of choice, you will be able to trace CSS properties.

This is generally how CSS debugging is done.

```
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
    background: url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
}
```

This seems to be causing your issue:

```
background: url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

But less the image not being available:

```
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

Is forcing your browser too interprate the background color as white, an accepted paramater of the CSS `background` property.

Comment: That definitely does seem to be causing my issue, is that built into Jquery? Thats quite odd as its not part of my code.

Comment: @Colin I would string search `rgb(255, 255, 255);` or `#FFF` inside the accordian libary you are using, no harm done in removing a style attribute.

Comment: Ah, I am just testing it on JSFiddle using Jquery 1.9.1 

So when I take this live, I believe this should not happen?

Comment: @Colin The first problem is that the background image isnt available. The background color `#FFF` is the fallback. If those properties are being injected into the DOM, that's an action of the library you are using. When I said library I meant the slider library. Oops I can see how that was unclear :)