# White in middle of Accordion - JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, accordion

Why is there a giant white space in the middle of my accordion content?

This is how I have my .css, and it works completely with the exception of the white space in the middle.

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    background-color: #dcaf4d;
    color: #42dc86;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

Here is an example of the white space:

http://jsfiddle.net/bQ5Gd/5/

And before you ask, [What is causing this white box inside my Jquery Accordion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028943/what-is-causing-this-white-box-inside-my-jquery-accordion?rq=1) does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's caused by this:

```
.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #AAA/*{borderColorContent}*/;
  background: #FFF/*{bgColorContent} url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png)/*{bgImgUrlContent}*/ 50%/*{bgContentXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgContentYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgContentRepeat}*/;
}
```

It's in the `jquery-ui.css` file around line 246.

An alternative is to change your own CSS. Try changing this:

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    background-color: #777;
}
```

to this:

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    background: #777;
}
```

Comment: ? I do not have that in my code, nor is it in the fiddle posted above.

Comment: I am using my jquery like this:      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>       How would i go about fixing that?

Comment: It's in the jquery-us.css file, and it does appear in your fiddle. Open your web inspector on that accordion box and you'll see it. :-)

Comment: Thank you for finding the problem.  Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: You could either dig into the jquery-ui.css file and make a change, or override it in your own style sheet.

Comment: Hmmm...sounds a bit out of my league.  Thanks for your help tho

Comment: jquery UI 1.9.2 is the jquery library; it's "prepared" with that code

Comment: Actually, it might just reqire a simple CSS fix in your own style sheet. Post updated. Try changing `background-color` to `background`. That will override the other style.

Comment: I gave you a zero-liner fix. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is because the default background is assigned by an background image so setting it to none should solve it

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    background-image: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #777;
    color: #000;
    border: none;
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height: 15pt;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p8saM/)

Comment: BAM!  IOU one Arun!  Too easy! Just added background-image: none; and everything is perfect!  Thanks!

Comment: actually decided to use ralph's fix of removing -color.  Thanks tho!!